# I need query to list error code in postgresql 13

Tags: postgresql, logging, error-code

I want to list all the error code  that has been occurred since one month for auditing purpose.
I have tried many ways but no luck. Please share me the query or table name in which I can find Error code that has been occurred.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can only get this information in the log.

If you use the "stderr" format, make sure to include `%e` in `log_line_prefix`, but for automated processing, the "csvlog" format is preferable.

Comment: is there any other way as this could be time consuming and I have to submit this report on monthly basis.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no alternative.

Comment: @SadamhHussain It might be time consuming the first time but it should be easy to automate.

Comment: You could evaluate the log with some tool outside the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the log files into your server using a foreign data wrapper.  But assuming you rotate your log files more than once  month, you would need to concatenate them somehow.  This will let you use SQL methods to analyze the data, while leaving the data outside of the database.

The docs for the [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/file-fdw.html) have good instructions on how to do this, other than the part about dealing with log rotation.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes, I have done as per your instruction, can you please share the location of log/pglog.csv or how i can see the error code. I am sorry but I am very fresh to Postgresql.